# Magento EE 1.14.2 - Cache problems on cms/block since upgrading CE 1.7.0.2 to EE 1.14.2

Tags: php, magento, caching, enterprise

We migrated a website from 1.7.0.2 Community to 1.14.2 Enterprise version.

Since, we have caching problems of some static CMS blocks on the entire site. You can watch the homepage. Block are reapeting and mix themself.

We activated : **CONFIG + LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG  + BLOCK_HTML  + TRANSLATE + COLLECTION_DATA + EAV +  CONFIG_API  + CONFIG_API2 caches.**

Before that we used memecache but the problem is still there with "file" cache.

FPC_Enterprise is disabled for now (problem is there when set to yes too), eventually, we want to install Amasty_FPC_Enterprise extension in the future.

The bug is randomly and can affect every call like : `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ID')->toHtml()...` You can see four call to CMS static block (cf. two news screenshots). But, the rendering of this blocks is "mixed" with another CMS blocks (in fact, "usbrama, "produit ecolo", "lots pub"). It's totaly crazy.

Did you ever see such things?

Screenshot 1 BUG with cache:

[image]

Screenshot 2 Normal rendering without cache: 
[image]

**Symptoms**

Caching problems of some static CMS blocks on the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, my solution is [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71705/cms-block-caching-issue-in-ee-1-14-2)

Basically the cms/block content is now cached in EE 1.14.2 but the cache key is not set correctly. I just wrote a small extension that overrides the cms/block class and sets the cache key based on the blockId. This worked for me.